# EF Gather all child records into list with a parent member

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Assume

```
Author
{
    int Id
    string Name
    bool Active
    bool ShowOnBookWall
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
Book 
{
    int id
    int AuthorId
    bool Active
    string Name  
}
```

and that I need a viewModel like:

```
BooksViewModel
{
     int BookId
     int AuthorId
     string AuthorName
     string BookName
}
```

How do I fulfil that view model with LINQ?

I know, and have seen SelectMany to get the list of all children books;

```
db.Authors.Where(a => a.Active && a.ShowOnBookWall)
     .SelectMany(author => author.Books)
     .ToList();
```

But I am getting stumped when I need to include parent table data in that list like Author Id and AuthorName.

How do I structure the LINQ to include those?

```
           db.Authors.Where(a => a.Active && a.ShowOnBookWall)
                .SelectMany(author=> author.Books).ToList()
                .Select( w=> new BooksViewModel()
                {
                    AuthorName = db.Authors.First(ar => ar.Id == w.AuthorId).Name,
                    AuthorId = w.AuthorId,
                    BookId = w.Id,
                    BookName=w.Name,
                });
```

Is this a sensible thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a property on the `Book` entity to reference the `Author` like so:

```
public class Book 
{
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And then do something like:

```
db.Books.Where(book => book.Author.Active && book.Author.ShowOnBookWall)
    .Select(book => new BooksViewModel
    {
        BookId = book.Id,
        AuthorId = book.Author.Id,
        AuthorName = book.Author.Name,
        BookName = book.Name
    })
```

Comment: While the other answer also works, with my modifications, I believe this solution keeps my code simpler - even if the underlying EF code to support this is more expensive? I would like to do some load tests between the two methods

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
db.Authors.Where(a => a.Active && a.ShowOnBookWall)
          .SelectMany(author => author.Books,
               (authorObj, bookObj) => new { authorObj, bookObj })
          .Select(x => new BooksViewModel
                 {
                     AuthorName = authorObj.Name,
                     AuthorId = bookObj.AuthorId,
                     BookId = bookObj.id,
                     BookName = bookObj.Name
                 }).ToList();
```

You can flatten the `Book` object using `SelectMany` and project it with `Author` object.

Comment: the .Select(x => new BooksViewModel has an error that says .Select is ambigious between IEnumberable and IQuerable

Comment: If I add: (authorObj, bookObj) => new { authorObj, bookObj }).ToList() then the authorObj and bookObj are not resolved...

Comment: VS 2013 with EF 6.1.2..and...any other details needed?

Comment: I did a bit of research on your method: I think you meant:             books = db.Authors.Where(a=>a.Active && a.ShowOnBookWall).ToList().
                SelectMany(author => author.Books.Where(book => book.Active), 
  (author, book) => new BooksViewModel
            {
               BookId = book.Id,
               AuthorId = author.Id,
               AuthorName = book.Author.Name,
               BookName = book.Name
            }).ToList();

Comment: @Robert- I think that should work. I am sorry, I am on mobile and I am not able to test.

Comment: For code simplicity (for now - I'll test for efficiency later) I'll be going with other answer