# Retrieve inner database field in a foreach with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a "Finalidade" table which is son of the "Insumo" table.

In the following code:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var model = db.Insumos;

foreach (var register in model)
{
    data.Custo = register.Finalidade.Descricao == "Revenda"
        ? data.Custo
        : data.Custo - data.CrdtIpi;
}
```

I need to retrieve the value of the inner field "Finalidade.Descricao" so that I can compare to my string. The problem is, as it is son of Insumo the whole thing come as null and my program won't work.

As I don't have how to use "Include" with "register" I'm not able to retrieve the value I need.

How can I retrieve the value of "register.Finalidade.Descricao"?

Comment: Another option is to use ViewModels and use LINQ to build what you need. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093915/ef-gather-all-child-records-into-list-with-a-parent-member).

Comment: Was my solution able to assist you?

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `.Include()` on the object named `register`. You can use it when you initialize the `model` property.

```
// .ToList is optional
var model = db.Insumos.Include(x => x.Finalidade).ToList();
```

You have to use [eager loading](http://www.itorian.com/2013/06/what-is-eager-loading-and-what-is-lazy.html) to accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Let me know if this helps!